# Trying to access image through string on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to retrieve image from database in Laravel but I am unable to do so using string value .

my store method in controller

```
  public function store(CreatePostsRequest $request)
    {

      $image= $request->image->store('posts');

        Post::create([
          'title'=>$request->title,
           'description'=>$request->description,
           'content'=> $request->content,
          'image'=>$request->image

        ]);

        session()->flash('success','Post Created Successfully.');

      return redirect(route('posts.index'));

        }
```

in my .env file I have updated

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

I have already tried

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I can see easily the hashed value of image in the app/storage/posts
but what i am trying to do is to store the hashed value of image in database but instead 
C:\Users\zaeem\AppData\Local\Temp\php216B.tmp the value is stored in database . any idea how I can store the hashed value 
such as the one in image 
[image: u can see the hashed value]

i am trying to now fetch my image from the database using img tag but it shows nothing

```
 @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
    <td> <img src="{{$post->image}}" width="60px" height="60px" alt=""> </td> 
    <td>
        {{$post->title}}
    </td>
    </tr>  

    @endforeach
```

Comment: You are storing `$request->image`, which is the temp file on upload, instead of `$image`, the result from your storage command.

Comment: thanks alot mate :) thank u so much bro ;)

Comment: Sure no problem

Comment: @JeremyHarris i am having another lil probelm when i try to show my image i am unable to fetch my image .how can i fetch my image and show it in the page .. i am editing the question how i am trying to fetch the image .

Comment: That is probably better as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

for get image and move it in the public folder and save image path in database do like following:

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$imageName = rand(1000000, 9990999) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path = '/upload/images/'   //this is for example
$image->move(public_path() . $path .  $imageName);
Post::create([
    'title'=>$request->title,
    'description'=>$request->description,
    'content'=> $request->content,
    'image'=> $path . $imageName
]);
```